# my files in upload folder just get specialpermission of IIS_USER

Tags: wordpress, iis, file-permissions, user-permissions

I run the `wordpress` on `IIS` ,i have a folder named upload with full permission for IIS_USER,but when i upload a file as you can see in the picture ,the file just get the special permission and i can't see the uploaded picture in the admin panel why ?

[image]

as a note the parent folder i mean 6 and 2019 have full permission for iis user .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could make sure you have set the enough  iusr permission instead of checking IIS_USER permission.

You could see below image:

[image]

The IIS default anonymous account is IUSR, you could check it from below IIS setting.

IIS manamgent console -> authentication -> edit

[image]

Permission window:

[image]